# Why does it say response is not defined even though it is

Tags: python

It keeps telling me response is not defined.

```
while response not in Yes or No:
    response = input("Would you like to shut down the program?\nyes/no\n")
if response == "Yes":
    print("Goodbye.\n")
elif response == "No":
    print("Ok.")
    quit()
else: 
    print("I didn't understand that.\n")
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: because you are referencing `response` in the while statement before assignment from the input function.

Comment: From the code you posted, `response` is not defined in the first line, where you try and use it.

Comment: If the line `while response not in Yes_No:` is running first, before `response = input("something")`, then indeed, `response`, will not be defined when that first line is run, thus leading to your error. Assuming you didn't set `response = something` beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's not referenced above the code you provide, the first time through the loop, `response` is not defined. Only after the first call to `input()`. You need to initialize before the loop. Something like `response = None` should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python is case sensative, converted response to upper case.

response.upper() == "YES":

response.upper() == "No":

```
response = input("Would you like to shut down the program?\nyes/no\n") 
if response.upper() == "YES":
     print("Goodbye.\n") 
elif response.upper() == "NO": 
     print("Ok.") 
     #quit() 
else: 
     print("I didn't understand that.\n")
```